# Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]'

Tags: c#, bitwise-and

I'm trying to process a byte array retrieving from a sensor.
In the retrieved byte array, there will be a byte-mask, xx-xx-xx-xx, that tells me which data will be in the array.

The sensor mask:

```
DATA_1 0x00000001
DATA_2 0x00000002
DATA_3 0x00000004
DATA_4 0x00000008
DATA_5 0x00000010
DATA_6 0x00000020
DATA_7 0x00000040
DATA_8 0x00000080
DATA_9 0x00000100
DATA_10 0x00000200
DATA_11 0x00000400
```

This byte-mask 43-05-00-00, for example, tells me that data_1, data_2, data_7, data_9, data_11 will be in response array. I know this by using bitwise-and in Calculator app of Windows: in hex mode, type 543, click "And" button, then type the sensor mask (1, 2, 4, 8, 10,...). If the result is the same as sensor mask (1, 2, 4, 8, 10,...), this data is included. But I don't know how to achieve this in C#.

This is my ideal but it gave me error: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]'

```
int[] sensorMaskList = new int[length] {1, 2, 4, 8,... };
internal List<int> GetSelectedData(byte[] byteMask)
{
    List<int> lstDataIndex = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sensorMaskList.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] mask = BitConverter.GetBytes(sensorMaskList[i]);
        if (mask & byteMask == mask)
           lstDataIndex.Add(i);
     }
     return lstDataIndex;
}
```

Can someone give me some ideal. Thanks in advance and sorry for bad english

Comment: You are trying to use the bitwise &-operator on arrays. You cannot do that. You'll need to loop through each element in the array and use the operator on the elements themselves. I.e. use the &-operator on a `byte` not a `byte[]`.

Comment: Yes I know that, but in my case, the value is greater than value a byte can store, like 543 and 100, so I had to store it in an array. Will it be correct if I using bitwise &-operator on each byte instead of whole array ?

Comment: Yes, because bitwise operations are - as the word says - performed bit by bit without carry. `&` is not `+`!

Comment: Try this: `if (mask.Zip(byteMask, (m, bm) => (m & bm) == m).All(x => x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class to easily perform and operation

```
int[] sensorMaskList = new int[length] {1, 2, 4, 8,... };
internal List<int> GetSelectedData(byte[] byteMask)
{
    BitArray byteMaskBits = new BitArray(byteMask);
    List<int> lstDataIndex = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sensorMaskList.Length; i++)
    {
        byte[] mask = BitConverter.GetBytes(sensorMaskList[i]);
        BitArray maskBits = new BitArray(mask);
        if(maskBits.And(byteMaskBits) == maskBits)
        {
            lstDataIndex.Add(i);
        }
     }
     return lstDataIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the error message "Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]'" means is that you can not use the bitwise AND operator on variables of type array. You can only use them on a single integer or unsigned integer variable or two integer or unsigned integers can be bitwise ANDED together.

What you may want to do if you want to do it for the whole array is make up another array of equal size and AND each variable in the first array with each variable in the second array in the corresponding positions such that the first variable in the array 1 will be bitwise ANDED with the first variable in array 2 and so forth. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry but i don't get your point. what I want is apply operator '&' on 2 array. So you are telling me to create a third array, basing on one of the first two array, right ?

Comment: Possibly. Depending on what you want to do. I am not telling you to make a third array. I am just saying when you bitwise logical AND two variables they must either be unsigned integer or integer and preferably of the same width bitwise. You can not logical AND on a whole array because a whole array contains many individual variables not only one and this is the reason you are getting this error. bitwise logical AND applies only to bits in two variables for example I can bitwise logical AND int x with int y but I can not bitwise logical AND a whole array with another whole array.

Comment: byte[] mask = BitConverter.GetBytes(sensorMaskList[i]);
if (mask & byteMask == mask)

Comment: The line that is producing the error is the if statement since you are trying to bitwise AND the whole of the mask array which is an array of type byte with byteMask. This is not a legal operation. I am not sure exactly what byteMask is but if it is an array, which I am assuming this from the error message you are trying to bitwise AND two arrays together. This can not happen. Instead you can bitwise AND two individual variables of two arrays so a statement like mask[0] & byteMask[0] would be perfectly legal since you are bitwise ANDING two variables of type byte not two whole arrays.

Comment: Try to break down your problem and work on individual variables so that you are bitwise logical ANDING individual variables and put the result in a third array if that is the way you want to go, for example:

Comment: Array 1 input integer; Array 2 mask integer; Array 3 result integer;

Comment: for (arrayCounter = 0; arrayCounter < length; arrayCounter++)
{
 result [arrayCounter] = input[arrayCounter] & mask[arrayCounter];
}

Simple enough is it not, since you broke the problem down and you are working on individual variables not whole arrays.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks